# Multiple values of JsonObject without key into JsonArray

Tags: java, android

In android I want to make this structure of `jsonArray` :

```
[
    {duration: 1, price: 100},
    {duration: 2, price: 200},
    {duration: 3, price: 300},
    {duration: 4, price: 400}
]
```

I wrote this code, but its not correct. How can I resolve that so I can get output as above.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONObject oneMonth = new JSONObject();

try {
    oneMonth.put("duration", "1");
    oneMonth.put("price", "2");
    json.put("oneMonth", oneMonth);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject threeMonth = new JSONObject();
try {
    threeMonth.put("duration", "1");
    threeMonth.put("price", "2");
    json.put("threeMonth", threeMonth);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject sixMonth = new JSONObject();
try {
    sixMonth.put("duration", "1");
    sixMonth.put("price", "2");
    json.put("sixMonth", sixMonth);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject twelveMonth = new JSONObject();
try {
    twelveMonth.put("duration", "1");
    twelveMonth.put("price", "2");
    json.put("twelveMonth", twelveMonth);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    jsonArray.put(/*PUT OBJECTS HERE*/);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what happens if you do "jsonArray.put(onemonth);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this way:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

JSONObject oneMonth = new JSONObject();

try {
    oneMonth.put("duration", "1");
    oneMonth.put("price", "100");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject threeMonth = new JSONObject();
try {
    threeMonth.put("duration", "2");
    threeMonth.put("price", "200");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject sixMonth = new JSONObject();
try {
    sixMonth.put("duration", "3");
    sixMonth.put("price", "300");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject twelveMonth = new JSONObject();
try {
    twelveMonth.put("duration", "4");
    twelveMonth.put("price", "400");
      } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
     jsonArray.put(oneMonth);
     jsonArray.put(threeMonth);
     jsonArray.put(sixMonth);
     jsonArray.put(twelveMonth);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```